# word automation table of content

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, word-automation

I have a document in which I have some text and a table of content

```
foreach (Word.TableOfContents toC in wordDoc.TablesOfContents)
        {
            toC.Update();

        }
```

but the title have the same word at the beginning and I would like to remove that word in the table of content
 I tried something like

```
 toC.Range.Text = toC.Range.Text.Replace("text to be removed", "");
```

but it now looks messed up 
the alignment and spacing are ruined , does anyone knows how to change the text without messing with the layout of the table of content??!

it looks as if I hit a dead-end 
if there any other way to do this, like in the template , if I could somehow tell the table of content to replace the specified text with an emoty string when it is being generated, is there something like that??!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the best way to edit the TOC contents directly.
May be try this approach

1. All the TOC's are using "Heading" styles.
2. Create a copy of the Style say "NONTOCHeading"
3. Set the heading which you dont want to appear in TOC as "NONTOCHeading"
4. Update the TOC

Comment: that's a good solution but in my application I'd rather have them all in the same style, Found a way to replace the text without messing up the table of content

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved it like this

```
object findText = "text to be removed";
                object replaceText = string.Empty;
                object item = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
                object whichItem = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
                object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
                object forward = true;
                object matchAllWord = true;
                toC.Range.Document.GoTo(ref item, ref whichItem, ref missing, ref missing);
                toC.Range.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref missing, ref matchAllWord,
                                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref forward,
                                  ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceText, ref replaceAll,
                                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

but you shouldn't update the table of content or you'll need to replace the text manually